# Validación de base de datos de mySQL en PHP

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, validación

Soy aprendiz de programación y estoy haciendo un programa muy sencillo para una veterinaria, en este caso quiero hacerlo para el control de inventarios.
Actualmente ya tengo la conexión con la base de datos y los puedo modificar. Dicho esto, quisiera saber como puedo validar que el codigo del producto existe y que si es cierto me sume la cantidad que le ingreso en el formulario.

Les dejo lo que llevo por ahora.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

muchas gracias

Comment: debes colocar el codigo en texto.. dale en editar y agregar el codigo de tu pregunta de lo contrario sera cerrada sin respuesta!

Comment: Igual, para verificar si un dato existe basta con hacer un select...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> quisiera saber como puedo validar que el codigo del producto existe...

Para validar una variable, que en tu caso es la [variable superglobal](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.variables.superglobals.php) [_POST](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php), existen dos funciones que ofrece Php.

La primera es [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.isset.php).
Esta función te indica si la variable pasada por argumento existe.

```php
isset($_POST['codigoAlimento']); // Si el índice codigoAlimento existe en POST esto devuelve true, caso contrario devuelve false

// Ejemplo de uso
if( isset($_POST['codigoAlimento']) ) {
    // El usuario envio el código del alimento
} else {
    // El usuario olvidó enviar el código
}
```

Y la segunda función es [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.empty.php).
Con esta se puede validar la variable tanto si existe como si está vacía.

```php
empty($_POST['unidadesPedidoAlimento']); // Si no existe devuelve true, y si existe pero es una cadena vacía también devuelve true

// Ejemplos de uso
if( empty($_POST) ) {
    // El usuario no envió ni codigoAlimento ni unidadesPedidoAlimento
}
```